# Cross origin error in ajax call

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, mendeley

```
function getInfo()
{

    var URL="https://api-oauth2.mendeley.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=374&redirect_uri=https://localhost/api/mendeley/mendeley.php&response_type=code&scope=all&JSON=1";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "https://192.168.2.210/api/mendeley/mendeley.php",
        converters: {
            'text json': true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.content);


        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

when I call this function this gives me error
SyntaxError: syntax error

Comment: on what line do you get the error? and is it `syntax error` or `cross origin error` ?

Comment: if I put alert in error:function(e){} it gives me that alert

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

---

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> jsonpCallback
>  Type: String or Function()
>  Specify the callback
>   function name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of
>   the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to
>   let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage
>   the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to
>   specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of
>   GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this
>   setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return
>   value of that function.

`https://192.168.2.210/api/mendeley/mendeley.php` is not a valid JavaScript function name.

---

If I visit `https://api-oauth2.mendeley.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=374&redirect_uri=https://localhost/api/mendeley/mendeley.php&response_type=code&scope=all&JSON=1` or `https://api-oauth2.mendeley.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=374&redirect_uri=https://localhost/api/mendeley/mendeley.php&response_type=code&scope=all&JSON=1&callback=something`, I get an HTML document prompting me to log in.

You need to hit a real JSONP endpoint to use JSONP.

Comment: thank you for your ans. I put some lines in my ajax code            jsonpCallback: "result",
jsonp: 'callback',   and function result(data) {
        alert(data); 
        console.log(data);
    };

Comment: @sayali — This answer points out two problems. You addressed one of them. It isn't surprising that it doesn't work.